# Meta alerts in Nagios ? Alert if two other checks are failing

Tags: nagios

Is there a way in Nagios to do this ?

I want to send a CRITICAL alert if two checks are failing.

For example,
if service1 and service2 are CRITICAL send a CRITICAL alert.

To be more precise,

if service1 fails on host1 and host2, then send an alert.

Comment: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/check_multi/details

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/347759/monitor-multiple-webs-within-a-server-in-nagios/348952#348952